# Compare 1st column of the 1st file and 2nd column of the 2nd file and matching

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, r

File1: Excel file (.xls)

```
UN          ID    St      M1    M2       SE    DOF  PV        PA            FC
17127159    0   -5.9    297.3   765.7   0.22    4   0.003   0.00389231  2.57536
17127163    2   -3.87   189.914 492.307 0.3548  4   0.0179  0.01795     2.59226
17127167    4   -3.8908 339.136 855.276 0.3429  4   0.0176  0.017       2.52192
17127171    6   -3.922  390.44  986.365 0.340   4   0.0172179   0.01721 2.52627
17127175    8   -4.715  536.072 1210.65 0.2492  4   0.00920158  0.00920 2.258
```

File2: Text file (.txt)

```
UNIT_ID   UN      TID        X       E       GG7     J     O
0      17127159 16657436 353.568 335.295 221.717 815.654 684.85
1      17127161 16657436 11.0842 7.01459 7.33511 11.2121 12.6268
2      17127163 16657450 221.647 226.774 136.274 431.32  392.533
3      17127165 16657452 5.02182 3.41172 4.12834 6.90306 4.91183
```

If 1st column of 1st file matches with 2nd column of 2nd file extract the matched rows of 2nd file from column 3 to column 9 and save them in the first file.

Can anyone help me ?

Output should be saved in a new file

output:

```
UN        ID   St  M1    M2    SE   DOF PV    PA    FC    TID     X  E  GG7  J O
17127159  0   -5.9  297.3   765.7   0.22    4   0.003   0.00389231  2.57536  16657436 353.568 335.295 221.717 815.654 684.85
```

Comment: R isn't really on topic here. You might do better asking on [so]. Anyway, please [edit] your question and i) show us your desired output (use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make it look right); ii) explain what the 1st file is. Is it a text file, an Excel XML file or a binary Excel file? We can only help if it is simple text.

Comment: Yes I did @terdon

Comment: You still haven't explained what you mean by "Excel file" and your desired output seems to only be the headers, with no values for X,E,GG7,J or O. And why did 2.57536 become 2.57? Do you want rounding? And, if so, why not 2.58? You have to explain exactly what you need or we won't be able to help.

Comment: Excel file is .xls and Text is .txt files

Comment: I made the changes for my output. please let me know if u need any other info @terdon

Comment: `.xls` could be many things. Is it a text file or is it binary? Can you read it with, for example, `more File1`?

Comment: Also, why isn't UN `17127163` in your output?

Comment: It can be but I just gave only one as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9; next} 
              {
                if($1 in a){
                    print $0,a[$1]
                }
               }' file2 file1
UN          ID    St      M1    M2       SE    DOF  PV        PA            FC TID  X   E   GG7 J   O   
17127159    0   -5.9    297.3   765.7   0.22    4   0.003   0.00389231  2.57536 16657436    353.568 335.295 221.717 815.654 684.85  
17127163    2   -3.87   189.914 492.307 0.3548  4   0.0179  0.01795     2.59226 16657450    221.647 226.774 136.274 431.32  392.533
```

#### Explanation

Awk splits each input line into fields (at whitespace, by default), making the 1st field `$1` the 2nd `$2` etc. The special variable `NR` is the current input line number and `FNR` is the current line number of the file being read. Therefore, when processing multiple files, the two are equal only while the first file is being read.

- `NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9; next}` : if we're reading the first file, save fields 3 through 9 (joined by tabs) as the value in the array `a` whose key is the 2nd field. Then, skip to the `next` line.
- The `next` ensures that the rest of the script will not be run for the first file (`file2`) but only the second (`file1`).
- `if($1 in a){ print $0,a[$1] }` : we're now in the second file (`file1`). If the first field exists as a key in the `a` array (`if($1 in a)`), then print the current line `$0` and the value stored in `a` for `$1`: fields 3 through 9 from `file2`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please explain about the solution once like what it does? It will be useful for my other data too.

Comment: Could you please explain about the solution once like what it does? It will be useful for my other data too.

Comment: @user3351523 I added an explanation. If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites. Also, please don't post the same comment twice like that. We are all volunteers here, I had seen the first one and would have answered as soon as I could.

Comment: it worked but column names are not in one row. it looks like this.                      UNIT_ID UnitName TranscriptID X_8__HuGene_2_0_st_.mdp_LEVEL E__HuGene_2_0_st_.mdp_LEVEL GG7__HuGene_2_0_st_.mdp_LEVEL J__HuGene_2_0_st_.mdp_LEVEL O__HuGene_2_0_st_.mdp_LEVEL T__HuGene_2_0_st_.mdp_LEVEL
 Statistics Mean1 Mean2 StandardError DegreeOfFreedom P-Value P-Adjusted FoldChange NewFC

Comment: @user3351523 if it doesn't look like what I have shown you above, then your files are not what you show in your question.

Comment: The column names from file2 are in first row and column names from file1 are in second row.

Comment: Could you please check the output once. I had updated now. This is the final output I need now.

Comment: @user3351523 are you sure? have you tried making your terminal window wider so that long lines aren't folded?

Comment: @user3351523 what? That is completely different to what you had originally asked for! Don't change your requirements after someone has spent time trying to help you. That just means we both wasted our time. If you need to do something else than what you originally requested, post a new question.

Comment: No. Im very sorry. This is the final one I need now. very sorry

Comment: @user3351523 nevertheless, that's not how this site works. Please take the [tour] and read our [help]. You ask a question, if you get a helpful answer you upvote it, if it answers your question, you [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. If you then have another question or realized that you asked the wrong question, you should post a new question.

Comment: It gave all the values which I need but I dont know why thce columns from file1 are in firstline and columns fron file2 are in next line

Comment: @user3351523 did you try making your terminal window wider?