# Compare 1st column of the 1st file and 2nd column of the 2nd file and get the the output as following

Tags: text-processing, awk

**File1: Excel file (.xls)**

```
UN          ID    St      M1    M2       SE    DOF  PV        PA            FC
17127159    0   -5.9    297.3   765.7   0.22    4   0.003   0.00389231  2.57536
17127163    2   -3.87   189.914 492.307 0.3548  4   0.0179  0.01795     2.59226
17127167    4   -3.8908 339.136 855.276 0.3429  4   0.0176  0.017       2.52192
17127171    6   -3.922  390.44  986.365 0.340   4   0.0172179   0.01721 2.52627
17127175    8   -4.715  536.072 1210.65 0.2492  4   0.00920158  0.00920 2.258
```

**File2: Text file (.txt)**

```
UNIT_ID   UN      TID        X       E       GG7     J     O
0      17127159 16657436 353.568 335.295 221.717 815.654 684.85
1      17127161 16657436 11.0842 7.01459 7.33511 11.2121 12.6268
2      17127163 16657450 221.647 226.774 136.274 431.32  392.533
3      17127165 16657452 5.02182 3.41172 4.12834 6.90306 4.91183
```

If 1st column of 1st file matches with 2nd column of 2nd file the output should look like the following

```
UN         FC        TID       X       E       GG7     J     O
17127159  2.57536  16657436 353.568 335.295 221.717 815.654 684.85
17127163  2.59226  16657450 221.647 226.774 136.274 431.32  392.533
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If that's an actual excel file, you'll have to save it in tab-separated text format.

Comment: I did that but still the UN FC and TID are saved in only one column

Comment: how is this any different from your question yesterday?  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273403/compare-1st-column-of-the-1st-file-and-2nd-column-of-the-2nd-file-and-matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8; next} 
              {
                if($1 in a){
                    print $1,$10,a[$1]
                }
               }' file2 file1
UN        FC        TID       X         E         GG7       J         O
17127159  2.57536   16657436  353.568   335.295   221.717   815.654   684.85
17127163  2.59226   16657450  221.647   226.774   136.274   431.32    392.533
```

If the spacing is important (it isn't to most programs but can be for humans), you can do:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{
               a[$2]=sprintf("%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s",$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8);
               next;
              } 
              {
                if($1 in a){
                    printf("%-10s%-10s%10s\n", $1,$10,a[$1])
                }
               }' file2 file1
UN        FC        TID       X         E         GG7       J         O         
17127159  2.57536   16657436  353.568   335.295   221.717   815.654   684.85    
17127163  2.59226   16657450  221.647   226.774   136.274   431.32    392.533
```

Comment: Could you please check the output which I need. The first column i need is UN not ID

Comment: @user3351523 whops, sorry, my bad! Fixed.

Comment: it worked but UN, FC and TID are combined in one column

Comment: @user3351523 then, again, the data you show doesn't accurately represent the data you have. You have still not explained what you mean by "Excel file" (although [I asked you](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/273403/22222) three times). That might be the source of the problem.

Comment: there is no problem with the data and even Excel file is saved in tab separated text format. But still I see in the output that UN, FC and TID in the same column. I saved the output file in .txt format

Comment: @user3351523 please ping me in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat).

Comment: +1. In your first solution there will be a mix of spaces and tabs in the output. That may be the "same column" issue.

Answer (score 0):

here is something it might help you try looking for more on web...

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$3;next}{print $0,a[$2]?a[$2]:"NA"}' file2 file1
```

Comment: It gives all the columns from file1. that is not what I need.